# Creating Site on Netlify using CURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, netlify

So, I am able to use the curl commands currently to GET information about sites I have on netlify.  However, according to the API docs I should be able to create a site as well using POST.  For the life of me I cannot seem to figure out whats happening.  When running this the page thinks for a long time, then refreshes and returns an empty response, and no site is created.

```
                    $ch = curl_init();

                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/sites");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

                    $headers = array();
                    $headers[] = "User-Agent: AppName (accountEmail)";
                    $headers[] = "Content-Length: 1000";
                    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer MyAPIAuthKey";
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
                    }
                    curl_close ($ch);

                    print $result;
```

Here is the Netlify API doc specifically referring to the "Create Site" section (3rd down) https://www.netlify.com/docs/api/#sites

Any idea what I'm missing here?  Like I said, I auth correctly and can GET all the data I want from my account.  I just can't seem to POST anything.

---

************************************************* UPDATED *************************************************

---

I'm now passing some properties, however getting a Request Timeout.

```
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.netlify.com/api/v1/sites");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"name\":\"awb-test\"");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10000);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

                    $headers = array();
                    $headers[] = "User-Agent: AWB (myemail@)";
                    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
                    $headers[] = "Content-Length: 1000";
                    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer MyAPIkey";
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
                    }
                    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: You are not sending any data with that request. From the docs it looks like to need to provide a JSON string with the properties listed.

Comment: The Docs state "POST /api/v1/sites will create a new site" and you "can" set props.  I was trying to just get it to work and then expand it.  TBH I'm completely new to using curl.  How would I build the props out and send them with the POST?

Comment: If I add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"name\":\"awb-test\", \"force_ssl\": true}");` I get a different error.  I get a "client taken too long to issue request".

Comment: Maybe you need to send the Content-Type header: `Content-Type:application/json`

Comment: I've added the Content Type.  I've also set the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to 10,000 seconds, but I'm still getting the "Your Client has taken too long to issue its request".

Comment: This was a question asked in parallel in the helpdesk and it seems that the "hardcoding" of a Content-Length that was incorrect was the culprit - Netlify was waiting for "the rest" when the request was finished from php's point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fool stated in the comments under the OP, the issue was the hard coded Content-Length.  To correct I built an array of the POST data, json encoded it and use string length to pass the appropriate value.

```
                    $post_data = array(
                        'name'      => '',
                        'force_ssl' => true,
                        'repo'      => '',
                    );
                    $post_data = json_encode($post_data);

                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, been struggling with this. How about posting the whole working code for all to see:)